# Brauer pairs associated to a normalizer subsystem in the fusion system of a block of a finite group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, modular-representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic $p$. Let $b$ be a block of $kG$ and let $(P,e)$ be a maximal $(G,b)$-Brauer pair. For every subgroup $Q$ of $P$ write $e_Q$ for the unique block of $kC_G(Q)$ satisfying $(Q,e_Q)\leq(P,e)$. Also set $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{F}_{(P,e)}(G,b)$, the fusion system of $b$ associated to the maximal Brauer pair $(P,e)$.

Let $Q$ be a fully $\mathcal{F}$-normalized subgroup of $P$. Then, as is shown in Linckelmann, *The Block Theory of Finite Group Algebras vol.2*, Proposition 8.5.4, $(N_P(Q),e_{N_P(Q)})$ is a maximal $(N_G(Q,e_Q),e_Q)$-Brauer pair and the associated fusion system is the normalizer fusion subsystem $N_{\mathcal{F}}(Q)$. That is, $N_{\mathcal{F}}(Q)=\mathcal{F}_{(N_P(Q),e_{N_P(Q)})}(N_G(Q,e_Q),e_Q)$.

I am confused about a statement included in the proof of this proposition (Linckelmann's Proposition 8.5.4). Linckelmann claims that if $R\leq N_P(Q)$ then the pair $(R,e_{QR})$ is an $(N_G(Q,e_Q),e_Q)$-Brauer pair. Let's set $H=N_G(Q,e_Q)$. If Linckelmann's claim is correct then $e_{QR}$ is a block of $kC_H(R)$. Now by definition $e_{QR}$ is a block of $kC_{G}(QR)$. It is clear that $C_G(QR)\leq C_H(R)$, so $e_{QR}$ is at least an idempotent in $kC_H(R)$. But it is not clear to me why $e_{QR}$ is *central* in $kC_H(R)$.

Any help understanding this claim would be very appreciated. Thanks!